# Supporting Polish language without compiling with unicode character set

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a legacy C++ application which is not compiled with unicode character set. This application is able to support some European languages such as German, Portuguese etc. Now there is a requirement to support Polish language. My understanding is that these characters wont fit in ASCII character range and there is no way to support it other than migrating the application to use unicode character sets. Is this understanding correct? Is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

German won't fit in ASCII either (and I suspect the same applies to Portugese.). I suspect that you're actually using CP1252. A Polish Windows install will be running CP1250 instead. This gives you the missing characters.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, the OS will have set Polish as the default system locale which will set 1250 Code Page as the default code page and everything else should work as expected?

Comment: @Asha: That's the default, but it can be changed IIRC ("Language for non-Unicode programs" is the option)